# Correct way of calling AJAX to fetch from database

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently learning how to use AJAX and from what I can see online, the most common way of fetching data from a database is calling an AJAX function on delay loop of about 1 or 2 seconds. This seems a bit, untidy and make-do approach, not to mention putting a heavy load on the client side if a large application.

Therefore, my question is what is the correct way of making an AJAX call to fetch data from a database? (that will update automatically)

Thank you for your help.

Example of an AJAX function on a delay loop:

```
var my_delay = 1000;     
$(function() {
    callAjax();
});      
function callAjax() {
      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "display.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
            setTimeout(callAjax, my_delay);
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: Ajax is the easy/old way. A more suitable approach to receiving data from the server without requesting it is using websockets.

Comment: something like Ratchet?

Comment: if you're using PHP on server side, then yes.